# Inserting Values into a Database without hardcoding them SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Just wanted to know how I could create an order for someone (let's say John Cena), that was ordered and paid today. Then, add an item of 'Ice Cream' to the order, without hardcoding any of these values? I have attached an image of the database below. I am using SQL server. Thanks[image]

Comment: what do you mean by hardcoding? What would be your way "with hardcoding" and how you'd like to improve on that?

Comment: If everything happens in the same session you can use SCOPE_IDENTITY() function to get the current value.